# How did the Apache Maven repository get into my Android project?

Tags: android-studio, maven, gradle

When I build my Android project I can see it download files from the Apache Maven repository.

I only have the default repositories in my `settings.gradle` which come from an Android Studio example project.

And none of them is the Apache Maven repository as you can see. So why does it download files from the Apache Maven repository?

This is my settings.gradle:

```
pluginManagement {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        gradlePluginPortal()
    }
}
dependencyResolutionManagement {
    repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
rootProject.name = "OwnNativeBinderClient2"
include ':app'
```

Here are some log lines from the gradle build:

```
Download https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/ow2/asm/asm-analysis/9.2/asm-analysis-9.2.pom, took 82 ms (2,62 kB)
Download https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/ow2/asm/asm-commons/9.2/asm-commons-9.2.pom, took 78 ms (2,96 kB)
Download https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/ow2/asm/asm/9.2/asm-9.2.pom, took 81 ms (2,37 kB)
Download https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-stdlib-jdk8/1.8.20-RC2/kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.8.20-RC2.pom, took 117 ms (1,59 kB)
Download https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/commons-io/commons-io/2.4/commons-io-2.4.pom, took 110 ms (10,17 kB)
Download https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpmime/4.5.6/httpmime-4.5.6.pom, took 129 ms (5,24 kB)
Download https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/ow2/asm/asm-util/9.2/asm-util-9.2.pom, took 92 ms (2,94 kB)
Download https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/bouncycastle/bcpkix-jdk15on/1.67/bcpkix-jdk15on-1.67.pom, took 52 ms (1,46 kB)
Download https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/ow2/ow2/1.5/ow2-1.5.pom, took 19 ms (11,23 kB)
Download https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/glassfish/jaxb/jaxb-runtime/2.3.2/jaxb-runtime-2.3.2.pom, took 24 ms (5,57 kB)
Download https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/commons/commons-parent/25/commons-parent-25.pom, took 33 ms (48,3 kB)
```

Comment: `mavenCentral()` from your `settings.gradle` is literally the Apache Maven repository...